# json schema: Can we use "items" within an "object"

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

The keyword "items" seems to be associated with "array" in most json schema examples I ve seen. However I tried using it with an object using this useful tool: http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ (JSON Schema Draft 4) and it works. I can t find any documentation stating that this is legal although it feels right to me.

```
"value": { 
      "type": "object",
      "items": ...
}
```

Is this really legal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the documentation you are looking for.

> Some validation keywords only apply to one or more primitive types. When the primitive type of the instance cannot be validated by a given keyword, validation for this keyword and instance SHOULD succeed.
>
> - http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor8

To illustrate the concept, take this schema as an example.

```
{
  "items": { "type": "string" },
  "maxLength": 2,
  "required": ["foo"]
}
```

`["foo"]` validates

- `items` -> pass
- `maxLength` -> ignored
- `required` -> ignored

`{ "foo": "bar" }` validates

- `items` -> ignored
- `maxLength` -> ignored
- `required` -> pass

`"foo"` does not validate

- `items` -> ignored
- `maxLength` -> fail
- `required` -> ignored

`3` validates

- `items` -> ignored
- `maxLength` -> ignored
- `required` -> ignored

Although it is possible to write schemas this way, it is recommended to not mix type keywords within a single schema.  You get more readable schemas using `anyOf` instead.

```
{
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 2
    },
    {
      "type": "array",
      "items": { "type": "string" }
    },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "required": "foo"
    }
  ]
}
```